# Adding Exchange E-mail Alias in VB.NET or C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exchange-server, alias

Using .NET (VB or C#), how can I add an e-mail alias to a user in Active Directory?

I have written code to change the format of our usernames from "first_last" to "first.last.country" and I need to update the e-mail addresses as well.  Our solution is to add an alias e-mail to the users in exchange, but I don't know how I can do this using .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite old but, you never know who may need this info.

The modern way to handle `Exchange Server` and `Active Directory` issues at this level is not using `vb` or `c#`, sure you can, but the practical and fast) way to do it is using `'powershell'`.

On your exchange server use `Powershell ISE`; it isvery close to a programming language. There are multiple samples elsewhere of aliases handling.

Here you have the basics: You start loading your environment, your location and version may vary:

```
. 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1' 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

Apply your own logic to get the user you want to modify and the alias:

```
$mb = get-Mailbox .....
$mb | Set-Mailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $false
$alias = "newalias@domain"
if(-not($mb.EmailAddresses -ccontains $alias)){
  $mb | Set-Mailbox -EmailAddresses @{Add="$alias" }
}
```